# NSNumber: stringValue crashes, description works

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, exception, nsstring, nsnumber

`[measureValue stringValue]` gives me this exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString stringValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4dde570'

`[measureValue description]` works perfectly

But I think I should use `stringValue` in the code, right?

This is the code:

```
NSNumber *measureValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [cellContent integerValue]];

//if imperial (inches)
if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Measure"] isEqualToString:@"Imperial"] ) {

    //if height
    if ([currentQuestion isEqualToString:@"Height"]) {
        measureValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(2.54 * [measureValue doubleValue])];
    //elseif weight
    } else {
        measureValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(0.45359237 * [measureValue doubleValue])];
    }

    //NSLog(@"%@", [measureValue stringValue]);
    cellContent = [measureValue description];
```

Comment: It crashes because NSString does not respond to stringValue. Why are you setting measureValue to a string? Set it to a NSNumber.

Comment: And you ignored the warning from your compiler about incompatible pointer types why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 NSNumber *measureValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [cellContent integerValue]];
```

That line returns an NSString, not an NSNumber. You're sending stringValue to the NSString.